# Regarding Google places API "can't load search result"

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am facing problem in google places API as I am getting the response as "Can't load search result". I have restricted my key as well as I am using the latest Places API SDK that is "2.0.1".Please let me know if I am failing something to add in project

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Blooms Mobility. Please, consider adding some code. It will make it easier for people to help you. For more information, please take a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you please post your code implementation, manifest, build.gradle and logcat files? Also double check that your project has billing enabled and Places API enabled.

Answer (score 0):

@Blooms Mobility, welcome to StackOverflow !!

This might happen if you don't have a billing account associated with your project.
Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project

Also, if that answers your question, I will suggest before posting a new question, you search for similar questions on StackOverflow.
This practice helps reduce redundancy on the forum. I can see a couple of questions related to the same problem
[image]